# Cancel WebSocket connection when trying to connect (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, websocket

Is it possible to cancel WebSocket connection while trying to establish connection to the server?

Let's say user notified that it is a misspelled host and want to cancel request for establishing connection before onerror has raised like

> failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I tried to call close, but this does not cancel request. I even get warning in console:

> failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not achievable using `close()`, and seems not possible at all.

Also, unlike [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort), WebSocket have no `abort` method to achieve this.

The [WebSocket specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#network) do not mention any way of doing this, and setting the object to `null` does not do the trick.

The following example illustrates this by setting the WebSocket object to `null`, but still getting connection error message.

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://unknownhost.local');
ws.onopen = function() {
  console.log('ohai');
};
ws = null;
console.log(ws);

// > null
// > VM2346:35 WebSocket connection to 'ws://unknownhost.local/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Comment: Thanks, I read the documentation, but was surprised, that there is no abort and I want a confirmation.

Answer (score 3):

Since the two previous answers to this question have been posted the behaviour of  `close()` seems to have changed.

Quoting the [mozilla API docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/close):

> The WebSocket.close() method closes the WebSocket connection or connection attempt, if any. If the connection is already CLOSED, this method does nothing.

You could therefore do this:

```js
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://unknownhost.local');
setTimeout(() => {
  if (ws.readyState == WebSocket.CONNECTING) {
    ws.close();
    console.log("Connection cancelled.");
  }
}, 1000);
```

Which would cancel the connection attempt if the [readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/readyState) did not switch to `OPEN` yet.

I tried this, and it seems to work (tested on Firefox).

Comment: This should work :)

Answer (score -1):

close() method only terminates the established connections. 
For your case, you may use assigning your websocket handle to null where you want to stop it.

```
webSocketHanle = null;
```

By this assignment, your callbacks will not be activated.

But notice that it is quite fast process to getting response from server.