# How can I cancel the close event of document method- addEventListener('close')

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the next dialog of mdl:

```
document.getElementById('dialog').addEventListener('close', function (event) {
         event.preventDefault()



});
```

So I want to cancel this event. That I want the dialog to not close when I press the back button. This event can capture the close event but can't stop the event because cancelable property will be set to false.

Comment: if you cancel event of close, then you are opening connection? then change close to (open)?

Comment: it looks like it closes and reopens

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992879/cancel-websocket-connection-when-trying-to-connect-javascript there doesn't seam to be an way to stop websocket, in youre example you just listen for it..

Answer (score 0):

you can use `removeEventListener` but you have to pass the same event handler you have pass when you use `addEventListener`

```
const closerHandler = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

}

document.getElementById('dialog').addEventListener('close',closerHandler); 
...    
document.getElementById('dialog').removeEventListener('close', closerHandler);
```

or you can use rxjs `fromEvent`

```
const source = fromEvent( document.getElementById('dialog'), 'close');
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

later you can use unsubscribe method

```
 subscribe.unsubscribe()
```

Comment: you need to create a demo or share the more code so I cam help 